# mongoDB - $lookup - code 4570: arguments to $lookup must be strings

Tags: string, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm trying to write a Mongodb aggregation that do the following:
I have two collections, where there are two fields that apear in both collections, and I want to write a query that adds based on wether both of the fields are equal in both collections, a field that exists only in one of them.
Say that the first collection is A and the second is B. Say that these are the fields in both of them:
A: x, y, z, w.
B: x, y, u.
I want to add u to A, based on where x, y are both the same in A and B.
if this is a record in A: x=1, y=2, z=3, w=4 and B: x=1, y=2, u=6, I want:
A: x=1, y=2, z=3, w=4, u=6. (because x, y are equal in both collections).
I wrote the following:

```
 db.A.aggregate([
       {
          "$lookup":{
             "from":"B",
             "let":{
                "x":"$x",
                "y":"$y"
             },
             "pipeline":[
                {
                   "$match":{
                      "$expr":{
                         "$and":[
                            {
                               "$eq":[
                                  "$x",
                                  "$$x"
                               ]
                            },
                            {
                               "$eq":[
                                  "$y",
                                  "$$y"
                               ]
                            }
                         ]
                      }
                   }
                }
             ],
             "as":"res"
          }
       }
    ])
```

I need to add a project part, but the problem is that i get the **following error** (means res is not working):
"message" : "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { x: '$x', y: '$y' } is type object"
and code 4570

Notes:

1. I use mongo version 4.4.5
2. x in my db is of type string and y is of type int32. I tried to convert y to string, this is not the problem.
   If someone knows how to help I would appreciate that.

Comment: That query executes without errors on 4.4 server. Did you send it to a 3.4/3.6 server?

Comment: Thanks, I checked again and the server use 3 version and not 4 version.